# Create an Origin - Destination map using roadnetwork layer

Tags: qgis, network, origin-destination

I am using Qgis 2.14.2, I am trying to create a O-D using the road network that I have in a feature. Is any way or plugin that can help me to plot 500 trips using as a path my road network layer? I know about the flow map plugin, but I do not understand how I should apply it, and if my data would apply it.

My data looks like:

**ID - OrgX  - OrgY - DestX - DestY**

Comment: I know with Grass is it possible to do it as well but i am having lots of problems to set everything before to launch the network tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to a postgresql database and use pgrouting with Qgis 
Here are the features offered :

- All Pairs Shortest Path, Johnson’s Algorithm
- All Pairs Shortest Path,Floyd-Warshall Algorithm
- Shortest Path A*
- Bi-directional Dijkstra Shortest Path
- Bi-directional A* Shortest Path
- Shortest Path Dijkstra
- Driving Distance
- K-Shortest Path, Multiple Alternative Paths
- K-Dijkstra, One to Many Shortest Path
- Traveling Sales Person Turn
- Restriction Shortest Path (TRSP)

Comment: So I would need to add all my data into Postgresql and then move into QGIS?

Comment: there is a tool in Qgis called DB Manager, if you have your data as a vector layer in Qgis you can export it as a Postgresql table and then with the Postgresql's plugin Pgrouting you can have all the above functions

Comment: Great, I am trying to follow that Tutorial as well http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/pgrouting/

Do you think that one would be useful for my problem?

Comment: great tutorial, I worked before on a project using the pgr_Dijkstra and pgr_createTopology, plus you won't get lost you can can find in this forum people that developed those functions

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with your project